# Restrict SQL Server access for certain application

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to deny the access the DB as SA from SSMS but allow them to make changes through the other application when logged in as SA. I used the following code but system throwing error. Please suggest me to correct the following code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Tr_ServerLogon]
ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
declare @appname VARCHAR(512)
SET @appname = APP_NAME()

if ('.Net SqlClient Data Provider'=@appname)
GRANT DELETE ON [dbname].[dbo].[tablename] TO [username]
else
DENY DELETE ON [dbname].[dbo].[tablename] TO [username]

END
GO
```

Comment: If you're letting them access the DB as SA, you've got no way to stop them doing anything they want to. Don't use SA as a general purpose account.

Comment: What Damien said. The application should log in with an account that has appropriate rights, up to db_owner if necessary. People using SSMS should probably use their Windows accounts (or SQL Server accounts you create for them) and you should make a group for these accounts, where the group has the appropriate rights - it sounds like you're thinking db_datareader.